# How do I ensure results of streamed commands are output in the same order?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, stream

In a Node.js program that asynchronously handles lines of input constantly coming in from `stdin`, how can I ensure the asynchronous handlers print their results in the same order the inputs came in?

[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) `program.js` (dependency: `npm install split`):

```
var executeCommand = function(line) {
    setTimeout(function() { console.log(line); }, 1000 * Math.random());
};

var split = require("split");
process.stdin.pipe(split("\n")).on("data", function(line) {
    executeCommand(line);
});
```

Running `printf "A\nB\nC\nD\nE\nF" | node program.js` produces

```
B
E
A
D
C
F
```

This is because the handler (`executeCommand`) has an unpredictable delay, modelled here as a random `setTimeout`.  The "processing" (the `setTimeout`s) should happen concurrently, but their outputs (`console.log`s) should be in the same order as the constantly incoming inputs.

How can I make that happen?

---

I'd usually just exclaim "*It's [`Async.js`](https://github.com/caolan/async) time!*", but this time I can't see an appropriate existing helper:  Since tasks are constantly coming in, anything that operates on a fixed collection of inputs won't cut it.

Comment: Some piece of code (either yours or a library) will have to keep track of each request separately so they can be reordered and output only when the oldest request has arrived.  You will also have to unhide the async portion that is now buried inside of `executeCommand()` so it can be done on a callback that can be reordered.

Comment: @jfriend00 That sounds like a good approach. I'll look into `async`'s source and try to understand how the array-consuming helper functions do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

As [@Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27348854/how-do-i-ensure-results-of-streamed-commands-are-output-in-the-same-order/27349013?noredirect=1#comment43153518_27349013) and [@jfriend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27348854/how-do-i-ensure-results-of-streamed-commands-are-output-in-the-same-order/27349013?noredirect=1#comment43152494_27348854) pointed out, handler results must be queued to a queue that only allows dequeueing completed tasks.  A good time to check for finished tasks is whenever a handler completes.

A picture might clarify how it works:

[image: Parallel processing with a queue]

Turns out a [transform stream](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform_1) is a nice way to model that.  ("Stuff comes in and eventually stuff related to the incoming stuff comes out" is pretty much the description of a transform stream.)  Whenever results finish, completed tasks are pushed.

Here's the question's example, modified to work:

```
var Transform = require("stream").Transform;
var split = require("split");

var orderedParallel = function(worker) {

    var s = new Transform({ objectMode : true });

    var resultsQueue = [];

    var sendFinishedFromQueue = function() {
        while (resultsQueue[0] && resultsQueue[0].done) {
            s.push(resultsQueue.shift().data);
        }
    }

    s._transform = function(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        var resultObject = { done : false, data : null };
        resultsQueue.push(resultObject);
        worker(chunk, function(result) {
            resultObject.data = result;
            resultObject.done = true;
            sendFinishedFromQueue();
        });
        callback();
    };
    s._flush = function(callback) {
        // Do nothing.
        //
        // We don't have anything to flush, because as workers complete,
        // they'll handle sending any and all messages we're allowed to send
        // right now.
    };
    return s;
};

var executeCommand = function(line, cb) {
    setTimeout(function() { cb(line); }, 1000 * Math.random());
};

process.stdin.pipe(split("\n")).pipe(orderedParallel(executeCommand))
    .on("data", function(x) { console.log(x); });
```

To convince yourself it works, try a hundred parallel tasks:

```
for (( i=0; i<=100; i++ ))
do
    echo "$i"
done | node program.js
```

They should complete in parallel (within 1 second at random), but come out of the `orderedParallel` transform stream in order regardless.

Answer (score 0):

`async.queue` with limit of 1 and where the worker function both executes the command and prints the results will do it. You won't have optimal concurrency, but it will behave correctly, so I suggest coding that even if it's a stepping stone. Keeping the correct behavior but adding some concurrency will require both queueing the main work function but also some buffering of output in the case of output2 being ready before output1 arrives.

Comment: That's equivalent to [`async.forever`](https://github.com/caolan/async#foreverfn-errback).

Comment: Yeah but you need a convenient way to add new `data` events to the queue that is distinct from processing them.